# Angular 6 unit test - TypeError: Cannot read property 'ROOT_API' of null

Tags: unit-testing, angular6, karma-jasmine, app-config

I am getting an error while running a unit test in my angular project
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'ROOT_API' of null`

I am using "app.config" for the environment files to keep its assets folder and call the service. In the component call the API and work without any problem but while running unit test getting the error above mentioned.

Here are my files and folder structure
[image]

Here is the adaptor service file get method

[image]

Here is the service file

[image]

Unit test error screenshot below

[image]

Please help me out with the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to Provide `AppConfig`, in the `TestBed` configuration of your test.
(It would be helpful if you post your test, as well).

Comment: Already the "AppConfig" in the testbed providers, But I am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

In your AppConfig File changed the private value for empty and remove the null value.

```
private config: Object = '';
private env: Object = '';
```

It's working fine for me....